# How to restrict inserting duplicate pairs of values in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in MySQL DB (MariaDB):

```
CREATE TABLE `restrictions_projects` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `restriction_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `restrictions_projects`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `project_id` (`project_id`),
  ADD KEY `restriction_id` (`restriction_id`);

ALTER TABLE `restrictions_projects`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `restrictions_projects`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `restrictions_prfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`ID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `restrictions_prfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`restriction_id`) REFERENCES `restrictions` (`ID`);
COMMIT;
```

How can I restrict inserting duplicate pairs of `project_id` and `restriction_id`?

> INSERT INTO `restrictions_projects` (`project_id`,`restriction_id`)
>   VALUES (1,2) // ??? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `project_id`=1 AND
>   `restriction_id`=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE restrictions_projects
  ADD CONSTRAINT unq_restrictions_2 UNIQUE(project_id, restriction_id);
```

You can also do this using a unique index, which is effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need composite unique key on both column

```
UNIQUE (project_id,restriction_id)
```

You should alter your table to add unique key

```
ALTER TABLE restrictions_projects ADD CONSTRAINT restrictions_projects_uniq UNIQUE (project_id,restriction_id)
```